# Refinery CMS with Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx, refinerycms

I use thinking sphinx in my project on refinery cms. And I received this error when try to update any page:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)):
```

But when I create new page everything work fine.

I override standard refinery page model and add standard thinking sphinx define_index method:

```
define_index do
    indexes title
    indexes parts.title, :as => :part_title
    indexes parts.content, :as => :part_content
    indexes parts.body, :as => :part_body
    indexes slugs.name, :as => :slug_name
end
```

And this is the reason of this problem, because when I commented this lines everything start working fine, but of course search stop working.

What should I do to let them working together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thinking shpinx conflicts with acts_as_indexed gem, try to comment acts_as_indexed in your model.